# Multiple email attachments in Magento 2.4.1

Tags: magento2.4.1

How to send Multiple email attachments in mail Magento 2.4.1?

I tried `etc\di.xml`

`<preference for="\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder" type="\Vendor\Module\Magento\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder" />`

and in mail function:-

```
$transport = $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($template)
            ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
            ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
            ->setFrom($from)
            ->addTo($to)
            ->addAttachment($file, $name)
            ->addAttachment($file2, $name2)
            ->getTransport();
```

Comment: Did you created the addAttachment Method to your TransportBuilder class?